# How to open compose page of outlook after clicking on an image

Tags: outlook

any one tel me how to open outlook message box to send mail by clicking on an image. The compose page should open with email address To. Plz any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<img alt="hello" scr="abc.jpg" onclick="location.href = 'mailto:abc@abc.com'" />
```